# i.m getting this error i hope anyone can help me out with it

Tags: reactjs

i want to select post by it Id but I'm getting error but I've tried i've been working on this but it not working. i'm a beginner in react trying to understand a good concept ion how react works it a blog project using redux and using a fake  API call

```
 import { createSlice, nanoid, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import sub from "date-fns/sub";

const POSTS_URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    status: 'idle', //'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
    error: null
}

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk('posts/fetchPosts', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(POSTS_URL)
    return response.data
});

export const addNewPost = createAsyncThunk('post/addNewPost', async(initialPost)=>{
    const response = await axios.post(POSTS_URL,initialPost)
    return response.data 
 
});
const postSlice = createSlice({
    name:"posts",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        postAdded: {
            reducer(state,action){
                state.posts.push(action.payload)
            },
            prepare(title, content, userId) {
                return {
                    payload: {
                        id: nanoid(),
                        title,
                        content,
                        date: new Date().toISOString(),
                        userId,
                        reactions: {
                            thumbsUp: 0,
                            wow: 0,
                            heart: 0,
                            rocket: 0,
                            coffee: 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        },
        reactionAdded(state, action){
            const {postId, reaction} = action.payload
            const existingPost = state.posts.find(post => post.id === postId)
            if(existingPost){
                existingPost.reactions[reaction]++
            }
        }



    }, 
    extraReducers(builder){
        builder
        .addCase(fetchPosts.pending, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'loading'
        })
        .addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'succeeded'
            // Adding date and reactions
            let min = 1;
            const loadedPosts = action.payload.map(post => {
                post.date = sub(new Date(), { minutes: min++ }).toISOString();
                post.reactions = {
                    thumbsUp: 0,
                    wow: 0,
                    heart: 0,
                    rocket: 0,
                    coffee: 0
                }
                return post;
            });

            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            state.posts = state.posts.concat(loadedPosts)
        })
        .addCase(fetchPosts.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.status = 'failed'
            state.error = action.error.message
        })

        .addCase(addNewPost.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            action.payload.userId = Number(action.payload.userId)
            action.payload.date = new Date().toISOString();
            action.payload.reactions = {
                thumbsUp: 0,
                hooray: 0,
                heart: 0,
                rocket: 0,
                eyes: 0
            }
            state.posts.push(action.payload)
        })
    },

})

export const selectAllPosts = (state) =>state.post.posts;
export const getPostStatus = (state) =>state.post.status
export const getPostError = (state) =>state.post.error


export const selectPostById = (state, postId) =>{
    state.posts.posts.find(post => post.id === postId)
   
}



export  const { postAdded, reactionAdded } = postSlice.actions

export default postSlice.reducer
```

this is the errror im getting when i try to inspect the error and the reason why it is not working

```
post-slice.js:113 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'posts')
   
        
       The above error occurred in the <SinglePostPage> component:
```

this is the function where i create the selectedPostbyId

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux' 
import { selectPostById } from '../../store/post-slice'

import PostAuthor from './PostAuthor';
import TimeAgo from './TimeAgo';
import ReactionButton from './ReactionButton';

 import { useParams } from 'react-router';

export default function SinglePostPage() {
    const {postId} = useParams();

    const post = useSelector((state) => selectPostById(state, Number(postId)))
    console.log('hello',post)



    if(!post){
        return(
            <section>post not found</section>
        )
    }
  return (
    <article>
        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
        <p className=''>
            <PostAuthor userId={post.userId}/>
            <TimeAgo timestamp={post.date}/>

        </p>
        <ReactionButton post={post}/>
    </article>
  )
}
```

Comment: import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postReducer from "./post-slice"
import userReducer from './user-slice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        post:postReducer,
        user:userReducer
    }
})
export default store;  this is the reducer that what im using to access it

Answer (score 0):

On line `113` of your `post-slice.js` file, inside the `selectPostById` function, you are doing `state.posts.posts.find()`. You are accessing `posts` twice, I believe.

```js
export const selectPostById = (state, postId) =>{
    // only access state.posts
    state.posts.find(post => post.id === postId)
   
}
```

Also above that function you are accessing state via `stat.post.posts` it should be `state.posts`.

```js
// above selectPostById function

export const selectAllPosts = (state) =>state.posts;
export const getPostStatus = (state) =>state.status;
export const getPostError = (state) =>state.error;
```

See if this is the issue :)

Comment: import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import postReducer from "./post-slice"
import userReducer from './user-slice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        post:postReducer,
        user:userReducer
    }
})
export default store;   that is my reducer store that what i'm using to access it